# Wordpress shortcodes in the wrong place

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I'm making wordpress plugin and I want to use shortcodes to insert some quite huge code inside post. I got this simple code that simulates my problem

```
function shortcode_fn( $attributes ) {
    wanted();
    return "unwanted";
}
add_shortcode( 'simplenote', 'shortcode_fn');

function wanted(){
    echo "wanted";
}
```

and post with this content

```
start
[simplenote]
end
```

that gives this result:

```
wanted
start
unwanted
end
```

and I want it to insert "wanted" text  between start and end.
I know easiest solution would be to just return "wanted" in wanted(), but I already have all these functions and they're quite huge. Is there a easy solution without writing everything from scratch?

@edit: maybe is there some way to store all echoes from function in string without printing it?

Comment: I don't think there's a way around this as the functions to generate the shortcode output are executed before the outputting of the page/post content, hence why wanted is shown above in your example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An easy workaround is to use [Output control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions:

```
function shortcode_fn( $attributes ) {
    ob_start(); // start a buffer
    wanted(); // everything is echoed into a buffer
    $wanted = ob_get_clean(); // get the buffer contents and clean it
    return $wanted;
}
```

Comment: I did it, and it works partially. Text is visible between start and end, but it also prints function before start. Is there a way to suppres it?

Comment: It should be suppressed. This is the original code: https://eval.in/143153
Result: wanted start unwanted end

This is with output buffering: https://eval.in/143155  
Result: start wanted unwanted end

Comment: It works, my bad :) I used ob_get_content instead, now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Overview

> When the_content is displayed, the shortcode API will parse any
>   registered shortcodes such as "[myshortcode]", separate and parse the
>   attributes and content, if any, and pass them the corresponding
>   shortcode handler function. Any string returned **(not echoed)** by the
>   shortcode handler will be inserted into the post body in place of the
>   shortcode itself.

So all shortcode function must be return, you can change your function "wanted" to this:

```
function wanted(){
    return "wanted";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Ruslan Bes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483663/ruslan-bes)' answer, the code looks like this:

```
function shortcode_fn( $attributes ) {
    ob_start(); // start a buffer
    wanted(); // everything is echoed into a buffer
    $wanted = ob_get_clean(); // get the buffer contents and clean it
    return $wanted;
}

add_shortcode( 'simplenote', 'shortcode_fn');

function wanted(){
    echo "wanted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress standard way would be to provide two functions. One, `get_wanted()` would *return* the wanted string; the other, `wanted()`, is just:

```
function wanted() {
    echo get_wanted();
}
```

So you can do either, but only have the bulk of the code in one place. This is a common pattern in WordPress, e.g. [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) versus [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

As @Ruslan mentions, the most standard way without rewriting your existing function to build a string would be to use output control.